# unable to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.01

Tags: upgrade

I have troubles when upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.01. My steps:

1. In terminal I update using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. I run software Updater and click Upgrade:

[image]

3. I got a warning that third party sources are disabled. I click on close and the upgrade continues.

[image]

4. After a while I got this error:

[image]

I do not understand how can I solve it. Can you help me please?

Comment: You have software installed from some third party resources that has dependencies that cannot be resolved after the upgrade. You need to remove this first. Unfortunately, the message does not tell which package ... maybe if you update in the terminal via `do-release-upgrade` it will tell you more information.

Comment: You have two options: The fast and easy solution is to back up your data and then reinstall Ubuntu. This will wipe out the problematic non-Ubuntu source(s) and application(s). The slower but learning solution is to uninstall your non-Ubuntu software and disable the non-Ubuntu sources one-at-a-time until you happen to uninstall the software that caused the conflict. Then you can release-upgrade. Do not use that conflict-causing source again.